# immutable data with circular dependencies

Tags: c#, immutability

I have a bunch of classes which are supposed to represent data. These classes are nested, so they form a tree (or, in simple cases, a chain). Since the data should just be created once and then only read, I use classes with init-only properties:

```
public class Foo { public Bar Bar { get; init; } }
public class Bar { public Baz Baz { get; init; } }
public class Baz { public int Value { get; init; } }
```

In order to navigate such a tree/chain not just from top to bottom, I need an `Owner` (or `Parent`) property for each class. So let's assume I have it like this:

```
public interface IData { }

public class Data<OwnerType> : IData where OwnerType : IData
{ public OwnerType Owner { get; init; } }

public class Foo : IData { public Bar Bar { get; init; } }
public class Bar : Data<Foo> { public Baz Baz { get; init; } }
public class Baz : Data<Bar> { public int Value { get; init; } }
```

But now I have a problem with circular dependencies: In order to create a non-empty `Foo`, I must set its `Foo.Bar` property during construction. But that `Bar` object needs a `Foo` object as `Bar.Owner` property set during construction, which cannot be the `Foo` currently in creation (because it hasn't been created yet), although that's the one it should be.

```
var foo = new Foo { Bar = new Bar { Owner = foo, ... } }; // this does not work but this is what I want
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

I could make the `Owner` property have a (private) setter. But I don't like this because `private` doesn't say `this can be set only once`.

Comment: I don't think C# has any native support for this pattern.  Your options, as I understand them, are the private setter, a factory method to build the classes, and / or a guard clause in the setter that throws an exception if it has been called more than once.

Comment: I just thought of another possibility, though it's a bit messy in and of its self.  You could make the property read-only with a backing field, and hide a "SetX" method inside an explicitly implemented interface.  That still leaves the backing field modifiable from inside the class though.

Comment: With immutable data structures, it is not possible

Comment: Circular dependencies is almost always a sign of bad design. I suggest to keep data immutable, and a separate dictionary for this "parent" relationship. This will be cleaner and only slightly less performant (well, you use immutable data, performance is clearly not a primary concern here).

Comment: @freakish Doubly-linked lists are bad design?

Comment: @freakish What I have outlined above is a doubly-linked list. One direction is Foo -> Foo.Bar = Bar -> Bar.Baz = Baz, the other Baz -> Baz.Owner = Bar -> Bar.Owner = Foo. I don't see any "bad design" here.

Comment: @Kjara doubly-linked lists is a horrible design IMO (there is a reason why hardly anyone uses them). That doesn't mean they aren't useful, or should always be avoided. There are cases where they are better than dynamic arrays or other structures. Still, they are not easy to use, and typically mutable pieces are hidden under some interface. So I guess that the real question here is: what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Because maybe there are better structures for your problem.

Comment: @freakish I want my tree/chain-like structure to be navigatable into both directions and immutable.

Comment: biggest problem with double-linked lists or any distributed container/collection is cache coherency. Because of all the memory indirection, they are terribly slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"A"* solution would be to make the setter of `Data` public, and set it in the class constructor.

Note: IMHO `Data` is a bad name, So I renamed it:

```cs
public interface IsOwner { }

public class OwnedBy<OwnerType> where OwnerType : IsOwner
{ public OwnerType Owner { get; set; } }

public class Foo : IsOwner
{
    public Bar _bar { get; init; }
    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        bar.Owner = this;
        _bar = bar;
    }
}
public class Bar : OwnedBy<Foo>, IsOwner
{ 
    public Baz _baz { get; init; }

    public Bar(Baz baz)
    {
        baz.Owner = this;
        _baz = baz;
    }
}
public class Baz : OwnedBy<Bar>
{
    public int _value { get; init; }

    public Baz(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo(new Bar(new Baz(1)));
    }
}
```

edit: I missed the set-once item in your question.
You can indeed back the `Owner` up with a private field, ensuring it's set once

```cs
public class OwnedBy<OwnerType> where OwnerType : IsOwner
{
    private OwnerType owner;

    public OwnerType Owner { get => owner; set => owner ??= value; }
}
```

Or even throw an exception is set twice.

```cs
public OwnerType Owner
{
    get => owner; set {
        if (owner is not null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
           $"{nameof(Owner)} can only be set once");
        owner = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this does what he wants.  In your example, the `1` passed in the Baz's constructor would have to somehow be a reference to `foo` in order to match the functionality. He needs a reference inside  a `Bar` that points back to the specific `Foo` that contains the `Bar`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm open to feedback, but don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you expand a bit? To my best knowledge `Owner` _is_ the reference you are talking of.

Comment: @BradleyUffner No, this is exactly what I want. I did not even want to specify the owner in the construction of `Bar` and `Baz`, I just had to in my example code.

Comment: Maybe it's just too early in the morning for me to be looking at code, but I don't see how you can navigate back to the parent instance of a `Foo` given an instance of a `Bar` with this code.

Comment: @BradleyUffner You mean `Baz`. Well. take the final object `baz`. `Baz` and `Bar` inherit from `OwnedBy`, so both have the propery `Owner`. So `baz.Owner.Owner` will give you the `foo` object. (And good morning to you, have some coffee ☕ (meant nicely :) ))

Comment: Ahh yes, I missed the inherited `Owner` property in your code, even though I clearly saw it in the initial question. Thanks for waking me up! It's WAY too early.